# Bootstrap Unresponsive In Safari - Host: Google Drive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari, responsive-images

> **Note:** Google Drive no longer provides hosting. Thereby the information below (as well as any answer) is virtually irrelevant.

Bootstrap is not being applied on Safari Mobile.
I'm using Google Drive for hosting.

Website I'm working on: https://drpinson5.blogspot.com/

Screenshots:

> **Safari** (not responsive):

[image: Safari (not responsive)]

> **Chrome** (responsive):

[image: Chrome (responsive)]

Comment: Should be dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478447/google-drive-hosted-css-not-working/40478448#40478448

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there is no privilege access for non google login user. So make your `CSS` and `JS` files as public

You need to give the access to all these files, and also need to check with other browsers that are not logged in with google account.

```
<link href='https://googledrive.com/host/0B3X3aqxEWs4QZGtzMS16YVJrdkE' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='https://googledrive.com/host/0B3X3aqxEWs4Qa3JiSWt1Z1JNNlU' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script src='https://googledrive.com/host/0B3X3aqxEWs4QTFJ0ejUxZ0t0dFU' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='https://googledrive.com/host/0B3X3aqxEWs4QeVNqdjBYRkRMclU' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to access.

Comment: Google drive :Go to sharing settings => Advanced => Who has access => change => On - Public on the web and save.

Comment: This is no longer supported. See duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about bootstrap img-responsive, try to use pure css code and embed it to the image  html tag. And use ***Viewport-percentage lengths: the vw, vh, vmin, vmax units***. Vw (for width) and vh (for height) for sizing the image.

Here's the example code :

```
<img src="/images/xxx.jpg" style="width:100vh; height:150vh"/>
```

for more reference :
https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-css-values-3-20150611/#viewport-relative-lengths

hope this answer could fix your problem.